# Image & text in the same view

Tags: iphone, image, text, fonts

How can I put together on the same view, an image and text? I want something like the image inserted in the text view...
And how can I change the text's font. I mean, two kinds of fonts in the same text.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need an editable text view, the simplest route is to use a UIWebView for any kind of advanced text layout, and make your content as an HTML document.

Comment: Thank you so much, I`ll use this one

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches,

One, if you are not planning to reuse the view,

> 1. Create a view as v1
> 2. add the image view as the subview of v1
> 3. add the label with font 1 as the subview of v1
> 4. add the label with font 2 as the subview of v1

two, if you are planning to reuse the view,

> 1. subclass uiview as a new class
> 2. in the initWithFrame method of the new class add the image view as
>      subview
> 3. add the label with font 1 subview
> 4. add the label with font 2 subview

three, if you are okay with working with graphics primitives,

> 1. subclass uiview as a new class
> 2. override the drawRect method in the class and paint out the image, and the
>      text.